# Не могу составить XMLHttpRequest запрос, аналогичный запросу на сайте

Tags: ajax, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Сайт http://www.пдд-онлайн.com/bileti-pdd/1-5. Содержимое генерируется JavaScript, необходимые данные для этого получаются по XMLHttpRequest. Не могу составить аналогичный запрос на своей странице. [Ссылка](http://www.xn----8sbka1akndeg.com/BiletModule/7F6A7860791E25CBF347A996AA9B9A6A.cache.html) на скрипт на сайте. Моя попытка скопировать (не работает):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://www.пдд-онлайн.com/BiletModule/GwtService", true);
request.setRequestHeader("X-GWT-Permutation", "7F6A7860791E25CBF347A996AA9B9A6A");
request.setRequestHeader("X-GWT-Module-Base", "http://www.пдд-онлайн.com/BiletModule/");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/x-gwt-rpc; charset=utf-8");
request.onreadystatechange = updatePage;
request.send("7|0|5|http://www.пдд-онлайн.com/BiletModule/|F4373CDFF2ABB37EC0FE5EDA83C19822|client.GwtService|getBiletVO|I|1|2|3|4|2|5|5|1|5|");

function updatePage() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
        var response = request.responseText;
        alert(response);
        document.body.innerText = response;
    }
}
</script>
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нельзя обращаться на другой домен, это политика безопасности браузера.

Comment: Спасибо за информацию